# MySQL Join, Force NULL Row

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do this -- I need to select all rows from table `t1`, join table `t2` -- but include a `null` row from `t2` for each record in `t1` (even if rows match in `t2`).

For my case, I actually need to do this with four tables:

Table `t1` has `t1_id`, `name`

Table `t2` has `t2_id`, `name`

Table `t3` has `t3_id`, `name`

Table `t4` has `t4_id`, `name`

I need to join them all to get something like:

```
-----------------------------
t1_id | t2_id | t3_id | t4_id
-----------------------------
1     | NULL  | NULL  | NULL
-----------------------------
1     | 1     | NULL  | NULL
-----------------------------
1     | 1     | 1     | NULL
-----------------------------
1     | 1     | 1     | 1
-----------------------------
```

This would be the final result of a join of the four tables, each having one row with an `tx_id` of 1.

Comment: Please elaborate, what do you want to accomplish with this join? Aggregates or subtotals of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All INNER JOINs and UNIONs maybe

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
select id t1_id,NULL t2_id,NULL t3_id,NULL t4_id from t1
union select t1.id,t2.id,NULL,NULL from t1
    inner join t2 using (id)
union select t1.id,t2.id,t3.id,NULL from t1
    inner join t2 using (id)
    inner join t3 using (id)
union select t1.id,t2.id,t3.id,t4.id from t1
    inner join t2 using (id)
    inner join t3 using (id)
    inner join t4 using (id)
;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
use test
drop table if exists t1;
drop table if exists t2;
drop table if exists t3;
drop table if exists t4;
create table t1
(
    id int not null,
    name varchar(20),
    primary key (id)
); 
insert into t1 values (1,'name1');
create table t2 like t1; insert into t2 values (1,'name2');
create table t3 like t1; insert into t3 values (1,'name3');
create table t4 like t1; insert into t4 values (1,'name4');
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> select id t1_id,NULL t2_id,NULL t3_id,NULL t4_id from t1
    -> union select t1.id,t2.id,NULL,NULL from t1
    ->     inner join t2 using (id)
    -> union select t1.id,t2.id,t3.id,NULL from t1
    ->     inner join t2 using (id)
    ->     inner join t3 using (id)
    -> union select t1.id,t2.id,t3.id,t4.id from t1
    ->     inner join t2 using (id)
    ->     inner join t3 using (id)
    ->     inner join t4 using (id)
    -> ;
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| t1_id | t2_id | t3_id | t4_id |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |
|     1 |     1 |  NULL |  NULL |
|     1 |     1 |     1 |  NULL |
|     1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

All the columns have id as a common name. If you want, I can adjust my answer with the id names

Comment: I marked this as right mainly for the use of the unions + null columns.  I was able to get mine to work as expected with LEFT joins.